# Does Cohen forcing add Sacks real?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is known that Sacks forcing does not add Cohen reals since it has the Laver property. I wonder if Cohen forcing can add a Sacks real. If $V$ is a model of ZFC, and $V[c]$ is the extension by adding one Cohen real, then in $V[c]$, is there any Sacks real over $V$?

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that the answer is no. But I can't find a source. Is there an obvious argument?

Comment: If $r$ is any real in the extension after adding a Cohen real, then $V[r]$ is either $V$ or $V[c]$ for some Cohen real $c$. But adding one Cohen is the same as iteratively adding two, so $V[c]=V[c_1][c_2]$ for some reals $c_1$ Cohen over $V$ and $c_2$ Cohen over $V[c_1]$. In particular, $V[r]$ is not a minimal extension.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Maybe post an answer?